# Stream, Util, and Crypto could not be found within the project or in node_modules

Tags: sql-server, database, react-native

I am trying to connect my react native android app to an existing SQL Server. But the problem is, I keep getting an error that says "stream could not be found within the project or in these directories: node_modules". And if I try installing the module, another error occurs regarding util could not be found. Up until I've installed crypto, the error changes. It would say something about

> error: Error: While trying to resolve module `crypto` from file
> `C:\react\connectDatabase\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js`, the
> package `C:\react\connectDatabase\node_modules\crypto\package.json`
> was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a
> `main` module field that could not be resolved
> (`C:\react\connectDatabase\node_modules\crypto\index.js`. Indeed, none
> of these files exist:
>
> *C:\react\connectDatabase\node_modules\crypto\index.js(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
> *C:\react\connectDatabase\node_modules\crypto\index.js\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
> at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\react\connectDatabase\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:311:17)

Comment: react native is not using node js

Comment: So, how do I connect my react native android application to an existing MSSQL server?